# I want to check my radio button with the data from back while I'm using ng-model and ng-value already

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button

I have `{{policy.isActiveInPolicyGroup}}` which is Boolean, I want the radio input be checked if it was true.

```
<div ng-repeat="policy in item.policies">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="item.selectedPolicy" id="policy_{{$index}}"
           name="test" ng-value="policy.id">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="test">
         {{item.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: yep, ng-repeat="policy in item.policies" . also it repeat as many as object i have in  policies

Comment: The `for` attribute for the `<label>` element should be `for="policy_{{$index}}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should know it's about value of inputs with radio type:

**Recommended**

> the radio inputs can't define by Boolean, if inputs are more than 2 we can't define value as Boolean so we should set a different value for each of them.
>
> **Ex:** `<input type="radio" name="test" ng-value="1">`, `<input type="radio" name="test" ng-value="2">` , `<input type="radio" name="test" ng-value="3">`

**Not Recommended**

> **Note:** Except when input number is 2: in this case we can set value `false` or `true`
>
> **Ex:** `<input type="radio" name="test" ng-value="true">`, `<input type="radio" name="test" ng-value="false">`

**radio input Note:**

> all radio inputs in one group should have same name

---

**checkbox input:**

> inputs with checkbox type by default define with Boolean value because we can set different name for each of them, and result is checked [true] or not [false]

---

**ng-model and ng-value**

Radio input should have two attributes `ng-model` and `ng-value` that because in angularjs logic `ng-model` should equal `ng-value` and can't do it by one attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Only set ng-model value like following:-

```
$scope.item.selectedPolicy = $scope.policy.id;
```

It will be checked if its ng-true value matched with its ng-model value.

Comment: it doesn't work ,  selectedPolicy  is already equal with policy.id .

Comment: true and "true" both are different so make sure it have correct value.

Comment: `ng-true` is not an AngularJS directive. Use `ng-true-value` with checkboxes. Use `ng-value` with radio buttons.

Comment: i also try that before

Answer (score 0):

### DEMO of Radio Buttons that Use Boolean Values<sup>[1](https://plnkr.co/edit/2UJChjsxtPDtqOWPuzps?p=preview)</sup>

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="radio"
             ng-model="model" ng-value="false">false<br>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" 
             ng-model="model" ng-value="true">true<br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model">check<br>
    </fieldset>
    model={{model}}   
  </body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<input type="radio"` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)
- [AngularJS `<input type="checkbox"` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: What about 3 or more radio input !? what we should do ?